# What is the "hasOwnProperty()" equivalent for interface?

Tags: actionscript-3

What is the "hasOwnProperty()" equivalent for interface?

I have found this related bug at Adobe: https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-27683

Any workaround except try..catch statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer is better, but you can also use

```
i['hasOwnProperty']('dispatchEvent')
```

Comment: That's wired, the method is there it just isn't defined at compile time. I have even commented on the Adobe ticket.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered this?

```
if("foo" in bar){ ...
```

where "foo" is the name of a property and bar is the object reference as Interface?

Here it is in action in a real world scenario:

```
import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

var i:IEventDispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
if("dispatchEvent" in i){
    trace(" I have dispatchEvent");
}
```